# Optional Parameter Index Route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, lumen

I'm looking to have an optional parameter on the index route like so:

```
$app->get('/{name?}', function ($name) {
      //Do Something here
});
```

I basically want to check and see if there is a parameter supplied. If so return a specific view, if not return the standard index view. For the life of me I can't get it to work, more than likely doing something stupid! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make the **$name** argument optional in your controller function so that it works when name is niot provided. Then, based on whether the parameter is set or not, you could return different views:

```
$app->get('/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
  if (is_null($name))  {
    return view('index');
  }
  else {
    return view('some_other_view');
  }
});
```

**NOTE**: In my opinion it would be more readable if you created 2 separate routes, one for index and one that takes the name parameter, as behaviour of your application in those 2 cases seems to be completely different.

Comment: Hi jedrzej, I eventually went with 2 separate routes as you suggested and it worked a treat. Thanks for your help!